# How to check whether the value of a variable is updated or not in Python

Tags: python

I am new to the python and here I have a quick question.

say in a while loop, I have a variable called center, and center is a list, as shown above:

```
     M = cv2.moments(c)
    center = (int(M["m10"] / M["m00"]), int(M["m01"] / M["m00"]))
```

center will always be [x,y] and since M is dynamically changed all the time, so does the center.

My question is how can I know whether center is updated or not? If it is updated, how can I mathematically compare this the new center with the previous center?

Thanks.

Comment: Your best bet is to keep the previous value in a different variable.

Comment: Why not just have a list recording the history of center and append to it every time it is updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep track of `center`. To do this create a variable to hold the previous value. This can be initialised to `None` at the start as you don't have a previous value. For example:

```
previous_center = None

while True:    

    #
    # Your loop code
    #

    M = cv2.moments(c)
    center = (int(M["m10"] / M["m00"]), int(M["m01"] / M["m00"]))

    if center != previous_center:
        print("New center", center)
        previous_center = center
```